# How can I turn data below in to a 'time based' graph

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

In my spreadsheet I am collecting time periods when certain values have been changed. The user is restricted to 4 time periods. I would like to show the data based on those time periods.

I've included a mock up of the data and the type of graph I would like to create. I've tried to create it for the last hour but am obviously missing something so thought I'd ask around.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to generate a graph, or could you do what you want through conditional formatting in the cells of the spreadsheet?

Comment: A graph would have been my first choice but I'm going to be looking at CF - see comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use conditional formatting. One rule per colored column.

- Use "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- When the cell value is 1, make the font color red and the fill color red (1st column)
- Use *normal* cell formatting options to make the font color white - the conditional formatting will override this.

You've probably already tried something similar to this - maybe you could elaborate on where it is failing for you. I got the best results by applying the conditional formatting to the first row in a column, then removing the absolute cell reference and then using the Format Painter to copy the conditional format to the other cells in the column.

Comment: I hadn't even thoguht about CF, so thanks for bringing up the idea. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Worked fine. Maybe there is another 'graph way of doing this but the CF version gave me what I was looking for. Thanks